# call to function is ambiguous, but why?

Tags: c++, clang, overloading, ambiguity

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void x(int a,int b){
  cout<<"int int"<<endl;
}
void x(char a,char b){
  cout<<"char char"<<endl;
}

int main() {
  int a =2;char c ='a';
  x(a,c);
  return 0; 
}
```

call to 'x' is ambiguous in apple clang compiler, why?

for x(int,int), first argument is a direct match and second is a promotion
for x(char, char) first argument is a standard conversion as I know and also according to this answer-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184631/13023201

And promotion should be preferred over std conversion, then x(int,int) should be called. Then why is this ambiguous??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at how [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) describes the overload resolution process:

> **Best viable function**
>
> For each pair of viable function F1 and F2, the implicit conversion sequences from the `i`-th argument to `i`-th parameter are ranked to determine which one is better (except the first argument, the *implicit object argument* for static member functions has no effect on the ranking)
>
> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all arguments of F1 are *not worse* than the implicit conversions for all arguments of F2, and
>
> ...

`x(int, int)` is a better match than `x(char, char)` for the first argument, since `int` to `int` is an exact match and `int` to `char` is a conversion.  But `x(int, int)` is a *worse* match for the second argument, because it's a promotion instead of an exact match. So *neither* function is a better match than the other and the overload cannot be resolved.